# How to append rows to MS SQL Server database with pandas for different column names?

Tags: python, pandas

Create a database:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Sam', 'M'], ['May', 'F'], ['Ben', 'M']], columns = ['name', 'sex'])

df.to_sql('info', conn_str, index = False)
```

Next, we create a new dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['John', 20], ['Ken', 18]], columns = ['name', 'age'])
```

I want to append this dataframe to the created database. The values of 'age' of the existing three records are set to 'NULL', so do the values of 'sex' of the new two rows.

```
df.to_sql('info', conn_str, if_exists = 'append', index = False)
```

However, it returns error:

```
ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'age'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO info (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: (('John', 20), ('Ken', 18))] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

What should be the correct approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Wanna share the error?

Comment: Error added in the question.

Comment: The database wont accept the migration to new columns over a pandas insert statement. There are two things you can do: (1) migrate the db to add columns to the table or (2) download the data, append the new column and recreate the table.